# SQL/PHP array, server warning

Tags: php, sql, arrays, db2

I'm trying to pull info off of a db and store it in an array.  `$row` is returning information, while `$categories` is lazy and doesn't do anything.  There's a log warning on the server that says:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: CATID in /www/zendsvr/htdocs/public/test/index.php on line 29

`CATID` is auto-increment PK from about 1 to 1100.  I've also assigned `$row` entries to individual variables successfully, but this array just doesn't want to work.

```
$query = 'SELECT CATID, CATDSC, CATPID, CATFEAT, CATURL FROM cecart.categories
WHERE CATURL!=\'\' ORDER BY CATFEAT DESC, RAND()';

while (($row = $stmt->fetch(Zend_Db::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== false) {
  $categories[$row['CATID']] =
    array('CATID' => trim($row['CATID']),
          'CATDSC' => trim($row['CATDSC']),
          'CATPID' => trim($row['CATPID']),
          'CATFEAT' => trim($row['CATFEAT']),
          'CATURL' => ($cat_img_dir . trim($row['CATURL'])));
  print($row['CATID'] . ' | ' . $categories['CATID']); // line 29
}
```

line 29 outputs: x | 
should be x | x if the array was working properly

Comment: What does your query look like?

Comment: Yes, please show us your query, and maybe an indication of which line in your PHP is line 29.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print($row['CATID'] . ' | ' . $categories['CATID']); // line 29
```

I'm guessing you meant to look up `$categories[$row['CATID']]`, not `$categories['CATID']`. There is no `$categories['CATID']`.

Comment: thanks, this is what worked:
print($row['CATID'] . ' | ' . $categories[$row['CATID']]['CATID']);